# How do I download only some data of a specific kind with appcfg.py download_data?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a kind in `ndb` with many (millions) of entities.  I would like to get some of this data from production to use in my development environment.  I know that if I download all the entities it will cause the `dev_appserver` to run very slowly and probably even crash before finishing the upload.

Below is the process I use to `get` and `set` the entities.

Is there a way to get just a subset of the entities from production to upload to my local dev_appserver?

**Download Data:**

```
python appcfg.py download_data --namespace="namespace" --kind="kind" --url=https://"appid".appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename="filename"
```

**Upload Data:**

```
python appcfg.py upload_data --namespace="namespace" --kind="kind" --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --application=dev~"project_id" --filename="filename" --num_threads=8 --email=foobar@nowhere.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the utility does not have provisions to download specific data that you would want.

I suggest the following approaches (you could go with any one depending on your requirements):

- Try out the `remote_api`. Using this you can connect to your Live instance Datastore via the local environment and fire specific queries and get the data. Refer to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi).
- Write your own handler on the live instance. You could pass it specific request parameters and it can fire up a query or two, collect the data into CSV,XML,JSON as you need and download it out for you.
- If you regularly need some sort of a backup, I suggest writing a Task on App Engine that could run frequently, extract out some data and maybe post it to an external web service or even Google Cloud Storage, from where you can then just use the command line util to pull down your data from the GCS buckets.